# How are Noble Ones harmed?

Tags: sila

I read the following on the internet:

> It all started by harming the Noble ones.

How can Noble Ones be harmed? Does the Buddha's Noble Path lead to increased susceptibility to being harmed?

Answer (score -1):

By disregard, by wrong view, by not wishing Noble Ones to resist, by encouraging to do not give to Noble Ones, by cheating, by taking not given, by what ever deed opposing and harming the Noble truth.

Of course, like Ven. Moggalana and others, might have rippen their kamma, they aren't touched at all by harm, but knowing the straight way to hell for those conducting gravely wrong, out of compassion, they might warn the fool without demand. That is, if a Noble One wishes, all he would, could, do.

Not even Devadata the Buddha could help in this way, yet for others, at least, it was a lesson.

Nobody can help good householder, as he for a long time avoided to follow Noble Ones advices and instead harmed the Gems all around. Long will be his helpless suffering unless he would came to mind and stop.

Four things declared by the Buddha one should approach with utmost carefully conducts, even if small, young: a snake, a fire, a young soldiers of good family and what ever young and new Samana.

The pain of touching the fourth lasts imessureable longer that being hit by fire, biten by a snake, imprisoned by a new King...

Still good householders view is directed toward fruits of deeds outwardly, and not of the cause of just own kamma.

The Noble One is freed of both, yet the fool not, and with wrong view able to kill even mother, father, hram and splitt the Gems. The Gems, those at the other shore, stay untouched. Fool! The fool not.

Understand?

[image]

So may good householder do what ever he thinks is proper or stay at home, stand and cry in pain. His choice.

Comment: thank you for this but it sounds wild

Comment: sorry but avoiding your advice is not avoiding advice of a Noble One. it seems Puthujjana monks are not Noble Ones. My impression is "Noble" = "Supramundane" = "Sunnata"

Comment: the monk in the photo looks like their mouth is open and drooling saliva.

Comment: Good householder has become a blind fool in householder-equanimity, regarding this as Noble. Because of this he heads with no turn back to hell. Even if understanding intelectual now right. His changes in this life had been played off already.

Comment: sorry but the last comment is not free from I & mine and the underlying tendency to conceit.

Comment: Noble has no impression. Good now. The other fools here will now go on and slayer him. There is no use in endless trying to give exists for fools as they are bond accoring to their evil deeds done toward the Gems. metta

Comment: Sorry but internet troll is not The Gems. The Noble Sangha is the Enlightened Sangha realised Emptiness.